# How can I fix this Android button onClick problem?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, kotlin, android-layout

I have tried to code a simple button in Android studio to display some simple message when clicked but all in vain. Below is an extract of my code, kindly help me understand what I might be getting wrong. Thank you!

```
package com.example.clinicappointment

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE
import android.view.Display
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun onTap(view: View) {
        textView3.text="My Summary to be displayed here!"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my button design<Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:onClick="onTap"**
        android:text="@string/patient_sumary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

Comment: Be informed questions are editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Geofrey Wasonga  Where is textView in your xml where you want to set the text on click of this button?
If it is there in your actual xml then you need to get a reference to the textview
private val textView3: TextView? = null
inside onCreate -> textView3 = findViewById(R.id.textViewID)
and then your button click should be able to work as expected.

Comment: thanks for your help. My textView is in my xml and it is named textView3. Thanks

Comment: @Geofrey Wasonga You can vote up if this solves your answer so that others can also take help from the answer.